# How to allocate 8kb memory for a character array and get the starting and ending address of it?

Tags: c, memory, driver, virtual-memory, contiguous

i need to allocate 8 kb to an array and need to get the starting and ending address of the array. then i need to check those virtual memory address are aligned contiguously or not in the actual physical memory. how to do that. please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: It is implementation-specific whether there is virtual memory, and if so whether you can access the virtual memory mapping tables in any way, and if so how. As far as standard C is concerned, there's no way to do this (well, you can attempt to allocate 8kb, but nothing after that). It would be a great shame if someone were to spend any time answering for, say, Windows device drivers, and then it turns out that in fact you're writing a user-mode device driver for Linux and the answers are completely different.

Comment: in that case you need to access the page table mappings, we need to know where you are working, in the user space or the kernel space.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MmAllocateContiguousMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It allocates a range of physically contiguous memory.